# How to make Qlabel not filling BoxLayout

Tags: python, pyqt, qlabel

I have QWidget, which contains QVBoxLayout and QLabel. Indeed when I put Qlabel inside QVBoxLayout it fill the QVBoxLayout. How to make QLabel ignore QVBoxLayout.

[image]

How to make the red border only around 'Text Label' ?

I've tried using setStyleSheet, setGeometry, but it didn't work. And I think using maximumsize is not the good option.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to use QSizePolicy so that instead of expanding, it contracts to the minimum:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class Label(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Label, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum)

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)

        lbl = Label("TextLabel")
        lbl.setStyleSheet('''background: red;''')
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(lbl, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Aligment didn't work if I set `label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)`, I need to do exactly like your code: `addWidget(lbl, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)` passing aligment value to optional aligment argument.

Comment: Any idea to give a padding like [this](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/17734314/52728300-a003cd80-2fe9-11e9-8a57-3426b5de2794.png) ?

Comment: done. I use [@S. Nick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54674721/6000005) code to accomplish that `'''
        color: white;
        font-size: 12px;
        border-radius: 4px;
        qproperty-alignment: AlignCenter;
        min-height: 50px;
        max-height: 50px;
        min-width: 250px;
        background: #1d2c3a;'''`

Comment: @azzamsa qss supports padding so you could apply it directly, the idea of S.Nick is good if you want to manually set the size of each part what I do not like since that depends on each platform.

Comment: So how to make padding with portability in mind ? Cause It will be cross platform app. Any idea beside using CSS value ?. the screenshot I took from telegram app, I don't know how they implemented it, [they didn't use css](https://github.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop/blob/032694ad9ec798889759c5b939c49f74b0767de4/Telegram/SourceFiles/history/history_widget.cpp#L6577), I don't know cpp :)

Comment: @azzamsa Now I'm working on something else, later I'll teach you a possible solution.

Comment: please tell me if you had better solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        label  = QLabel("TextLabel") 
        layout = QGridLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(label)

CSS = """
QLabel {
    font-family: Ubuntu-Regular;
    font-size: 12px;
    qproperty-alignment: AlignCenter; 
    color: blue;
    border: 3px solid red;
    border-radius: 4px;
    min-height: 40px;
    max-height: 40px;
    min-width: 48px;
    max-width: 100px;
    background: yellow;    
}
"""        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(CSS)
    ex = Widget()
    ex.show()
    app.exec_()
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I don't want to apply the css to whole app. `app.setStyleSheet(CSS)`

Comment: Your answer although it works for a particular case but in the general case it fails because if the size of the fonts changes you would have to adjust `min/max-width/height` which is annoying and untenable

Comment: Hi S.Nick, turn out your I use your CSS variable too, cause with only setSizePolicy, I can't make something like [this](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/17734314/52728300-a003cd80-2fe9-11e9-8a57-3426b5de2794.png). But I don't apply it to app level, only to QLabel. thanks a lot for the hint. Sorry I can only vote once.